# auto generate new columns based on similar definition sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that I need to get columns for the same metrics by up to different time points, so I need to write something like below:

```
select customer,

sum([Is NonRecurring Sale]+[Is NonRecurring Refund]+[Is NonRecurring Chargeback]) as net_report_bill_through,
    sum([net sales]) as report_revenue,
    MIN(transactiontimestamp) as report_date_min,
    MAX(transactiontimestamp) as report_date_max,

    SUM(case when transactiondatestamp >= billthrough_date and transactiondatestamp <= dateadd(day,5,billthrough_date) then ([Is NonRecurring Sale]+[Is NonRecurring Refund]+[Is NonRecurring Chargeback])
                    else 0 end) as g1_num_reports,
    SUM(case when transactiondatestamp >= billthrough_date and transactiondatestamp <= dateadd(day,10,billthrough_date) then ([Is NonRecurring Sale]+[Is NonRecurring Refund]+[Is NonRecurring Chargeback])
                    else 0 end) as g2_num_reports,
    SUM(case when transactiondatestamp >= billthrough_date and transactiondatestamp <= dateadd(day,15,billthrough_date) then ([Is NonRecurring Sale]+[Is NonRecurring Refund]+[Is NonRecurring Chargeback])
                    else 0 end) as g3_num_reports,
    SUM(case when transactiondatestamp >= billthrough_date and transactiondatestamp <= dateadd(day,20,billthrough_date) then ([Is NonRecurring Sale]+[Is NonRecurring Refund]+[Is NonRecurring Chargeback])
                    else 0 end) as g4_num_reports
into #report_info
from #report_transactions
group by customer
order by customer
```

So the aggregate columns `g1_num_reports, g2_num_reports, g3_num_reports, g4_num_reports` they are all similar, the only difference is the number of days in the `dateadd` function, for each of them, increasing from 5, 10, 15, to 20, at an interval of 5.

But potentially I will need many more similar columns with the number of days increased by 5 for each column.

Is there an easy way to simplify these task, so that I will just specify how many such columns I want and they can be generated automatically?

Comment: I might be completely off here, but you might possibly be able to accomplish this with PIVOT... http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx